# Output of a statsmodels regression

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I would like to perform a simple linear regression using statsmodels and I've tried several different methods by now but I just don't get it to work. The code that I have constructed now doesn't give me any errors but it also doesn't show me the result

I am trying to create a model for the variable "Direction" which takes the value 0 if the return for the corresponding date was negative and 1 if it was positive. The explinatory variables are the (5) lags of the returns. The df13 contains the lags and also the direction for each observed date. I tried this code and as I mentioned it doesn't give an error but says " Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.682314
         Iterations 5

However, I would like to see the typical table with all the beta values, their significance etc.

Also, what would you say, since Direction is a binary variable may it be better to use a logit instead of a linear model? However, in the assignment it appeared as a linear model.

And lastly, I am sorry its not displayed here correctly but I don't know how to write as code or insert my dataframe

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import os

import itertools

from sklearn import preprocessing

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import statsmodels.api as sm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std

...



X = df13[['Lag1', 'Lag2', 'Lag3', 'Lag4', 'Lag5']]
Y = df13['Direction']

X = sm.add_constant(X)


model = sm.Logit(Y.astype(float), X.astype(float)).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)

print_model = model.summary
print(print_model)
```

Edit: I'm sure it has to be a logit regression so I updated that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is unintentional, but it looks like you need to define X and Y separately:

```
X = df13[['Lag1', 'Lag2', 'Lag3', 'Lag4', 'Lag5']]

Y = df13['Direction']
```

Secondly, I'm not familiar with statsmodel, but I would try converting your dataframes to numpy arrays. You can do this with

```
Xnum = X.to_numpy() 

ynum = y.to_numpy()
```

And try passing those to the regressors.

Comment: the first part was unintentional, it was not displayed correctly. The second part I've tried several times before with the to_numpy code but that did not resolve the problem. Actually I used the astype(float) to get around that I believe.

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses: model.summary()